# How to get struct i2c_client *client structure inside kernel thread

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi4

I am now developing a kernel module to handle two digits 7-segment led indicator via I2C device on RaspberryPi4 with RaspberryPiOS.

This module uses kernel thread to handle 7-segment led display, change digit position.

Sending command to i2c device requires i2c_client* structure, it can be obtained via formal argument of probe function.

Kernel thread does not have formal argument of  i2c_client structure.

My solution is to store a pointer of i2c_client* structure into a global variable and use this pointer inside kernel thread, and call i2c function with this pointer.

My kernel module works well, at least now...

Do you have better solution to use i2c function in kernel thread? or exists better solution?

My entire code is below...

```
//i2c_7seg2_udev.c


#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>
#include <linux/delay.h> 
#include <linux/kthread.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");

#define DEVICE_NAME "i2c_7seg2_udev"

#define MINOR_BASE 0
#define MINOR_NUM  1

static unsigned int major_num;

struct cdev i2c_7seg2_udev_cdev;

void init_i2c_gpio(void);
void turn_off_7seg(void);
void turn_off_7seg(void);
void set_7seg(unsigned int number);
void change_7seg_keta(void);



#define LOOP_SLEEP_US (5000)

static struct task_struct *kthread;
static int dynamic_7seg_kthread(void *data);
static void init_kthread(void)
;

static int dynamic_7seg_kthread(void *data)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop()){

        change_7seg_keta();

        usleep_range(LOOP_SLEEP_US, LOOP_SLEEP_US * 2);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

static void init_kthread(void)
{
    kthread = kthread_create(dynamic_7seg_kthread, NULL, "dynamic_7seg_kthread");

    wake_up_process(kthread);
}


static int init_regist_device(void);

static struct i2c_client *i2c_client_data;

#define DRIVER_NAME "i2c_7seg2_udev"   

static struct i2c_device_id i2c_7seg2_udev_device_idtable[] = {
    {"I2C_7SEG2_UDEV", 0},
    { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, i2c_7seg2_udev_device_idtable);

static int i2c_7seg2_udev_device_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    if(init_regist_device() < 0){
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: initialize failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }



    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev_device connected.\n");
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "id.name = %s, id.driver_data = %ld", id->name, id->driver_data);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "device address is: 0x%02X\n", client->addr);
    
    i2c_client_data = client;
    
    init_i2c_gpio();
    
    set_7seg(12);
    
    init_kthread();
    return 0;
}


static int i2c_7seg2_udev_device_remove(struct i2c_client *client)
{
    dev_t dev;

    turn_off_7seg();


    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: wait for thread to be terminated.\n");
    kthread_stop(kthread);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: thread terminated.\n");
    
    dev = MKDEV(major_num, MINOR_BASE);

    cdev_del(&i2c_7seg2_udev_cdev);

    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_NUM);
    

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev_device disconnected.\n");
    return 0;
}

static struct i2c_driver i2c_7seg2_udev_device_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name  = DRIVER_NAME,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .id_table  = i2c_7seg2_udev_device_idtable,  
    .probe     = i2c_7seg2_udev_device_probe,    
    .remove    = i2c_7seg2_udev_device_remove,   
};


#define MAX_7SEG_KETA (2)
//NOTE: "KETA" means digit position, in Japanese.

static const unsigned int seg7_pattern[] =
//--gfedcba
{0b00111111, //0 
 0b00000110, //1 
 0b01011011, //2 
 0b01001111, //3 
 0b01100110, //4 
 0b01101101, //5 
 0b01111100, //6 
 0b00100111, //7 
 0b01111111, //8 
 0b01100111  //9 
};


unsigned char value_7seg[MAX_7SEG_KETA];


DEFINE_MUTEX(__mutex_value_7seg);


void set_7seg(unsigned int number){
    unsigned int i;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: value %d .\n", number);
    for( i = 0; i < MAX_7SEG_KETA; i++){
        value_7seg[MAX_7SEG_KETA - i - 1] = (number % 10) + '0';
        number = number / 10;
    }
    


}


void change_7seg_keta(void)
{
   static unsigned int keta = 0;
   unsigned char keta_shift;
   unsigned int number;

   keta_shift = 0x01 << keta;


   i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_client_data, 0x03, ~keta_shift); //P1に出力

   number = value_7seg[MAX_7SEG_KETA - keta - 1] - '0';

   
   i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_client_data, 0x02, ~seg7_pattern[number]); //P0に出力
   
   keta ++;
   if( keta >= MAX_7SEG_KETA ){
         keta = 0;
    }
}

void turn_off_7seg(void){
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_client_data, 0x02, 0x7F); //P0に出力
}

void init_i2c_gpio(void){
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_client_data, 0x06, 0x00);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_client_data, 0x07, 0x00);
    
}

static int i2c_7seg2_udev_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: opened.\n");
    return 0;
}

static int i2c_7seg2_udev_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: closed.\n");
    return 0;
}


static ssize_t i2c_7seg2_udev_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    unsigned char read_datas[MAX_7SEG_KETA + 2];
    unsigned long bytes_left;
    const unsigned long bytes_to_send = MAX_7SEG_KETA + 2;
    unsigned int i;


    for(i = 0; i < MAX_7SEG_KETA; i++  ){
        read_datas[i] = value_7seg[i];
    }
    
    read_datas[i]     = '\n';
    read_datas[i + 1] = '\0';


    bytes_left = copy_to_user(buf, read_datas, bytes_to_send);

    return (bytes_to_send - bytes_left);

}


static ssize_t i2c_7seg2_udev_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    unsigned char write_values[MAX_7SEG_KETA + 2];
    unsigned long bytes_left;
    const unsigned long bytes_to_send = MAX_7SEG_KETA + 2;
    int i;

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: write.");
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: write.");
    
    bytes_left = copy_from_user(write_values, buf, bytes_to_send);

    mutex_lock(&__mutex_value_7seg);
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_7SEG_KETA; i++){
        if( (write_values[i] >= '0') && (write_values[i] <= '9') ){
            value_7seg[i] = write_values[i];
        }
    }

    mutex_unlock(&__mutex_value_7seg);
    
    return (bytes_to_send - bytes_left);
}

struct file_operations s_i2c_7seg2_udev_fops = {
    .open    = i2c_7seg2_udev_open,
    .release = i2c_7seg2_udev_close,
    .read    = i2c_7seg2_udev_read,
    .write   = i2c_7seg2_udev_write,
};


int init_regist_device(void)
{
    int device_num = 0;
    int devnum_err = 0;
    int cdev_err = 0;
    dev_t dev;

    devnum_err = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, MINOR_BASE, MINOR_NUM, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (devnum_err != 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR  "devnum_err = %d\n", devnum_err);
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (device_num != 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR  "i2c_7seg2_udev: error_init_regist_device , %d\n", device_num);
        return -1;
    }

    major_num = MAJOR(dev);

    cdev_init(&i2c_7seg2_udev_cdev, &s_i2c_7seg2_udev_fops);
    i2c_7seg2_udev_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    cdev_err = cdev_add(&i2c_7seg2_udev_cdev, dev, MINOR_NUM);
    if (cdev_err != 0) {

        printk(KERN_ERR  "cdev_add = %d\n", cdev_err);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_NUM);
        return -1;
    }
    
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev: device registerd.\n");
    
    return 0;
}

static int i2c_7seg2_udev_device_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev device driver loaded.\n");

    i2c_add_driver(&i2c_7seg2_udev_device_driver);
    

    return 0;
}

static void i2c_7seg2_udev_device_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "i2c_7seg2_udev device driver unloading.\n");
    i2c_del_driver(&i2c_7seg2_udev_device_driver);

}


module_init(i2c_7seg2_udev_device_init);
module_exit(i2c_7seg2_udev_device_exit);
```

Comment: **Side note** Have you checked _drivers/auxdisplay/_ folder in the latest vanilla kernel? (v5.17-rc1 will be available on Monday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the function `kthread_create()` is `void *data`.
Right now you are passing `NULL`, you can pass your pointer to the `struct i2c_client` instead.
Then you can do:

```c
static int dynamic_7seg_kthread(void *data) {
    struct i2c_client *client = data;

    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        change_7seg_keta(client);

        usleep_range(LOOP_SLEEP_US, LOOP_SLEEP_US * 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thus eliminating global variable from the code.

Comment: Hi, Kirill. Thanks a lot. I will try this.